# Need help adding value to a variable

Tags: python

Here is the whole code section

```python
for entry in auth_log:
    # timestamp is converted to milliseconds for CEF
    # repr is used to keep '\\' in the domain\username
    extension = {
        'rt=': str(time.ctime(int(entry['timestamp']))),
        'src=': entry['ip'],
        'dhost=': entry['host'],
        'duser=': repr(entry['username']).lstrip("u").strip("'"),
        'outcome=': entry['result'],
        'cs1Label=': 'new_enrollment',
        'cs1=': str(entry['new_enrollment']),
        'cs2Label=': 'factor',
        'cs2=': entry['factor'],
        'ca3Label=': 'integration',
        'cs3=': entry['integration'],
    }

    log_to_cef(entry['eventtype'], entry['eventtype'], **extension)
```

In line 5 (`rt=`), I would like to add the timestamp output to a variable where I can call it later in the script.

Comment: You can do  `extension["rt="]` to get that value. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: You already did put it in a variable; it's safely saved in your dict.

Comment: no i wanna be able to use that value later in the script.
i mean. I wanna be able to call if i do print x (where x is the value)

Comment: @anwar_it Then store the dictionary in a more global scope or return it from this function, then index it as required as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the value from the dictionary directly with `extension["rt="]`?

If you are looking for a way to have a list of all the variables outside of your loop you can use this method.

Before your loop you should make an empty list like this:

`extensionRt = []`

Then after `extension` is created inside each loop use:

```py
extensionRt.append(extension["rt="])
```

You can then access the values in this list by index:

```py
extensionRt[YOUR INDEX HERE]
```